# How to write a common MySQL query which will return result when called from API function in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

Right now whenever I want to execute a mysql query in my api functions I create a DB connection , then executing the query and releasing the connection for each api function. The code gets messier  when nested DB query should be executed and Even I thought about performance issues since connections are continuously created and released . This is my current implementation

> dbServer.js

```
const db = mysql.createPool({
   connectionLimit: 100,
   host: DB_HOST,
   user: DB_USER,
   password: DB_PASSWORD,
   database: DB_DATABASE,
   port: DB_PORT
})

module.exports = db
```

> app.js (main file)

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
app.use(express.json())
const db = require('./dbServer')

require('./Backend/Routes/ApifileName')(app , db);

const port = process.env.PORT

app.listen(port)
```

> ApiFileName.js

```
const mysql = require("mysql")
const auth = require("../Middlewares/VerifyMerchantAuth")

module.exports = function(app , db){
    app.post("/v1/route" ,auth, async(req , res) => {

        let someParam= req.body.someParam;

        let sql_command = "SELECT * from table_Name where column_name = ?"
        let sql_query   = mysql.format(sql_command,[someParam])

        db.getConnection ( async (err, connection)=> {
            if (err) throw err;

            await connection.query (sql_query, async (err, result) => {
                connection.release();

                if (err) throw err;

                if(result.length == 0){
                    return res.json({error : "some error"})
                }

                return res.json({result : "some result"});
            })
        })
    })
}
```

> My Files Hierarchy

```
node_modules
package.json
app.js
dbServer.js
Backend -> 1. Routes -> ApiFileName.js
           2. Middlewares -> Here I want to write this sql function
```

My requirement now is I need to write a common function which takes **db** and **sql_query** as parameters and should return response if success or error.

I tried it myself but the mysql response comes after the api returns it's response. I tried using await , .then() but nothing worked.

Or Is this current implemented method is efficient already? Give your views.

Please Help me and Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A new connection for each SQL query is terrible for performance.  Have a single connection for the entire invocation of the app.  That may involve having a "global" or "static" place to hold the "handle" to the connection.

If you are in a web environment, you cannot keep the connection from one "web page" to the next.  Simply let it go and connect again on the next page.

Don't worry about "pools"; they done buy enough performance to worry about.

There is a *rare* case where you need more than one "connection" in an app -- if you are talking to different *servers*.  Within a single server, one connection can interact with all the databases and tables (that it has permission to touch).

Comment: I tried to get connection in app.js and sent it as parameter. But it was converted to undefined instead of object. What should I do then?

Comment: If the code to get the connection is displayed there, I don't understand it.